# How can I get back to having only the master bookmark in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I am very confused in what I did with this mercurial repository ... I reversed a commit and after that I was never able to have a "unique" structure in my repository again. Can someone help me?

```
> hg log

672[tip]: 670,671   9abd695c57ee   2020-02-14 10:01 +0100   
  commit before

671[localgit/master][master]:669   02169eecd8d0   2020-02-13 17:15 +0100 
  script to subscribe shared flows

670   922dcfabbc33   2020-02-13 15:34 +0100   
  script to subscribe flows

669[localgit/feature][feature]   126caa38767f   2020-02-13 10:22 +0100   
  debug algosec connection


> hg heads

changeset:   672:9abd695c57ee
tag:         tip
parent:      670:922dcfabbc33
parent:      671:02169eecd8d0
user:        grigoli
date:        Fri Feb 14 10:01:37 2020 +0100
summary:     commit before

> hg branches

default                      672:9abd695c57ee

> hg bookmarks

feature                   669:126caa38767f
master                    671:02169eecd8d0
```

Comment: see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Answer (score -1):

1. You can't "reverse" commit (or at least I can't translate this *your local term* to commonly-used lingua), you done something (that?, on which changeset?) different
2. You can see more useful picture of DAG (and other details) if you'll use something like
   `hg log -G -r 669:672`
3. I can see now ordinary mergeset (672) between two anonymous heads of default branch (and incorrect updating to changeset, performed before anonymous branching /bookmark was not activated before commit/ - `feature` bookmark is still on 669, while it expected to move with head of anonymous branch)